# Como usar función de botón en un evento?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito implementar un step progress. Buscando en google encontre este

[Ejemplo de step progress](https://oguzhanoya.github.io/jquery-steps/)

Necesito adaptarlo a un proceso de captura de huellas digitales.

Dejo aquí las librerías que utilizo para generar el step progress.

**Edición No. 1:**

Mi pregunta es.

Como puedo invocar esta : `[data-direction="next"]`

función usada desde html al hacer click en un boton:

```
<button data-direction="next" class="step-btn">Next</button>
```

La cual esta definida en de esta manera en un archivo js:

```
$footer.find('button[data-direction="next"]').hide();
```

De manera que pueda lograr la misma funcionalidad que botón.

**Edición No. 2:**

Bien, haciendo debug del código js, encontré estas funciones que son utilizadas en el proceso de crear los pasos:

**archivo Defaults.js**

```js
export default {
  startAt: 0,
  showBackButton: true,
  showFooterButtons: true,
  onInit: $.noop,
  onDestroy: $.noop,
  onFinish: $.noop,
  onChange() { return true; },
  stepSelector: '.step-steps > li',
  contentSelector: '.step-content > .step-tab-panel',
  footerSelector: '.step-footer',
  buttonSelector: 'button',
  activeClass: 'active',
  doneClass: 'done',
  errorClass: 'error',
};
```

** jquery-steps.js **

```js
/*!
   * Steps v1.0.1
   * https://github.com/oguzhanoya/jquery-steps
   *
   * Copyright (c) 2017 oguzhanoya
   * Released under the MIT license
   */
  
(function (global, factory) {
 typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(require('jquery')) :
 typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['jquery'], factory) :
 (factory(global.$));
}(this, (function ($$1) { 'use strict';

$$1 = 'default' in $$1 ? $$1['default'] : $$1;

var DEFAULTS = {
  startAt: 0,
  showBackButton: true,
  showFooterButtons: true,
  onInit: $.noop,
  onDestroy: $.noop,
  onFinish: $.noop,
  onChange: function onChange() {
    return true;
  },

  stepSelector: '.step-steps > li',
  contentSelector: '.step-content > .step-tab-panel',
  footerSelector: '.step-footer',
  buttonSelector: 'button',
  activeClass: 'active',
  doneClass: 'done',
  errorClass: 'error'
};

var classCallCheck = function (instance, Constructor) {
  if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) {
    throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function");
  }
};

var createClass = function () {
  function defineProperties(target, props) {
    for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
      var descriptor = props[i];
      descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false;
      descriptor.configurable = true;
      if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true;
      Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor);
    }
  }

  return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) {
    if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps);
    if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps);
    return Constructor;
  };
}();

var Steps = function () {
  function Steps(element, options) {
    classCallCheck(this, Steps);

    // Extend defaults with the init options.
    this.options = $$1.extend({}, DEFAULTS, options);

    // Store main DOM element.
    this.el = $$1(element);

    // Initialize
    this.init();
  }

  createClass(Steps, [{
    key: 'init',
    value: function init() {
  debugger;
      this.hook('onInit');
      var self = this;

      // step click event
      $$1(this.el).find(this.options.stepSelector).on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var nextStep = $$1(this).closest('li').index();
        var stepIndex = self.getStepIndex();
        self.setActiveStep(stepIndex, nextStep);
      });

      // button click event
      $$1(this.el).find(this.options.footerSelector + ' ' + this.options.buttonSelector).on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var statusAction = $$1(this).data('direction');
        self.setAction(statusAction);
      });

      // set default step
      this.setShowStep(this.options.startAt, '', this.options.activeClass);
      this.setFooterBtns();

      // show footer buttons
      if (!this.options.showFooterButtons) {
        this.hideFooterBtns();
        this.setFooterBtns = $$1.noop;
      }
    }
  }, {
    key: 'hook',
    value: function hook(hookName) {
      if (this.options[hookName] !== undefined) {
        this.options[hookName].call(this.el);
      }
    }
  }, {
    key: 'destroy',
    value: function destroy() {
      this.el.empty();
      this.el.removeData('plugin_Steps');
      this.hook('onDestroy');
    }
  }, {
    key: 'getStepIndex',
    value: function getStepIndex() {
      var stepIndex = this.el.find(this.options.stepSelector).filter('.' + this.options.activeClass).index();
      return stepIndex || 0;
    }
  }, {
    key: 'getMaxStepCount',
    value: function getMaxStepCount() {
      return this.el.find(this.options.stepSelector).length - 1;
    }
  }, {
    key: 'getStepDirection',
    value: function getStepDirection(stepIndex, newIndex) {
      var direction = 'none';
      if (newIndex < stepIndex) {
        direction = 'backward';
      } else if (newIndex > stepIndex) {
        direction = 'forward';
      }
      return direction;
    }
  }, {
    key: 'setShowStep',
    value: function setShowStep(idx, removeClass) {
      var addClass = arguments.length > 2 && arguments[2] !== undefined ? arguments[2] : '';

      this.el.find(this.options.contentSelector).removeClass(this.options.activeClass);
      var $prevStep = this.el.find(this.options.stepSelector).eq(idx);
      $prevStep.removeClass(removeClass).addClass(addClass);
      var targetStep = $prevStep.find('a').attr('href');
      $$1(targetStep).addClass(this.options.activeClass);
    }
  }, {
    key: 'setActiveStep',
    value: function setActiveStep(currentIndex, newIndex) {
      if (newIndex !== currentIndex) {
        if (newIndex > currentIndex) {
          for (var i = 0; i <= newIndex; i += 1) {
            var lastTab = i === newIndex;
            if (lastTab) {
              this.setShowStep(i, this.options.doneClass, this.options.activeClass);
            } else {
              this.setShowStep(i, this.options.activeClass + ' ' + this.options.errorClass, this.options.doneClass);
            }
            var stepDirectionF = this.getStepDirection(i, newIndex);
            var validStep = this.options.onChange(i, newIndex, stepDirectionF);
            if (!validStep) {
              this.setShowStep(i, this.options.doneClass, this.options.activeClass + ' ' + this.options.errorClass);
              this.setFooterBtns();
              break;
            }
          }
        }

        if (currentIndex > newIndex) {
          for (var _i = currentIndex; _i >= newIndex; _i -= 1) {
            var stepDirectionB = this.getStepDirection(_i, newIndex);
            this.options.onChange(_i, newIndex, stepDirectionB);
            this.setShowStep(_i, this.options.doneClass + ' ' + this.options.activeClass + ' ' + this.options.errorClass);
            if (_i === newIndex) {
              this.setShowStep(_i, this.options.doneClass + ' ' + this.options.errorClass, this.options.activeClass);
            }
          }
        }

        this.setFooterBtns();
      }
    }
  }, {
    key: 'setFooterBtns',
    value: function setFooterBtns() {
      var stepIndex = this.getStepIndex();
      var maxIndex = this.getMaxStepCount();
      var $footer = this.el.find(this.options.footerSelector);

      if (stepIndex === 0) {
        $footer.find('button[data-direction="prev"]').hide();
      }

      if (stepIndex > 0 && this.options.showBackButton) {
        $footer.find('button[data-direction="prev"]').show();
      }

      if (maxIndex === stepIndex) {
    debugger;
        $footer.find('button[data-direction="prev"]').show();
        $footer.find('button[data-direction="next"]').hide();
        $footer.find('button[data-direction="finish"]').show();
      } else {
        $footer.find('button[data-direction="next"]').show();
        $footer.find('button[data-direction="finish"]').hide();
      }

      if (!this.options.showBackButton) {
        $footer.find('button[data-direction="prev"]').hide();
      }
    }
  }, {
    key: 'setAction',
    value: function setAction(action) {
      var stepIndex = this.getStepIndex();
      var nextStep = stepIndex;
      if (action === 'prev') {
        nextStep -= 1;
      }
      if (action === 'next') {
    debugger;
        nextStep += 1;
      }
      if (action === 'finish') {
        var validStep = this.options.onChange(stepIndex, nextStep, 'forward');
        if (validStep) {
          this.hook('onFinish');
        } else {
          this.setShowStep(stepIndex, '', 'error');
        }
      }
      if (action !== 'finish') {
        this.setActiveStep(stepIndex, nextStep);
      }
    }
  }, {
    key: 'hideFooterBtns',
    value: function hideFooterBtns() {
      this.el.find(this.options.footerSelector).hide();
    }
  }], [{
    key: 'setDefaults',
    value: function setDefaults(options) {
      $$1.extend(DEFAULTS, $$1.isPlainObject(options) && options);
    }
  }]);
  return Steps;
}();

var other = $$1.fn.steps;

$$1.fn.steps = function (options) {
  return this.each(function () {
    if (!$$1.data(this, 'plugin_Steps')) {
      $$1.data(this, 'plugin_Steps', new Steps(this, options));
    }
  });
};

$$1.fn.steps.version = '1.0.1';
$$1.fn.steps.setDefaults = Steps.setDefaults;

// No conflict
$$1.fn.steps.noConflict = function () {
  $$1.fn.steps = other;
  return this;
};

})));
//# sourceMappingURL=jquery-steps.js.map
```

** Archivo Steps.js **

```js
import $ from 'jquery';
import DEFAULTS from './Defaults';

class Steps {
  constructor(element, options) {
    // Extend defaults with the init options.
    this.options = $.extend({}, DEFAULTS, options);

    // Store main DOM element.
    this.el = $(element);

    // Initialize
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
   debugger;
    this.hook('onInit');
    const self = this;

    // step click event
    $(this.el).find(this.options.stepSelector).on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const nextStep = $(this).closest('li').index();
      const stepIndex = self.getStepIndex();
      self.setActiveStep(stepIndex, nextStep);
    });

    // button click event
    $(this.el).find(`${this.options.footerSelector} ${this.options.buttonSelector}`).on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const statusAction = $(this).data('direction');
      self.setAction(statusAction);
    });

    // set default step
    this.setShowStep(this.options.startAt, '', this.options.activeClass);
    this.setFooterBtns();

    // show footer buttons
    if (!this.options.showFooterButtons) {
      this.hideFooterBtns();
      this.setFooterBtns = $.noop;
    }
  }

  hook(hookName) {
    if (this.options[hookName] !== undefined) {
      this.options[hookName].call(this.el);
    }
  }

  destroy() {
    this.el.empty();
    this.el.removeData('plugin_Steps');
    this.hook('onDestroy');
  }

  getStepIndex() {
    const stepIndex = this.el.find(this.options.stepSelector)
                             .filter(`.${this.options.activeClass}`)
                             .index();
    return stepIndex || 0;
  }

  getMaxStepCount() {
    return this.el.find(this.options.stepSelector).length - 1;
  }

  getStepDirection(stepIndex, newIndex) {
    let direction = 'none';
    if (newIndex < stepIndex) {
      direction = 'backward';
    } else if (newIndex > stepIndex) {
      direction = 'forward';
    }
    return direction;
  }

  setShowStep(idx, removeClass, addClass = '') {
    this.el.find(this.options.contentSelector).removeClass(this.options.activeClass);
    const $prevStep = this.el.find(this.options.stepSelector).eq(idx);
    $prevStep.removeClass(removeClass).addClass(addClass);
    const targetStep = $prevStep.find('a').attr('href');
    $(targetStep).addClass(this.options.activeClass);
  }

  setActiveStep(currentIndex, newIndex) {
    if (newIndex !== currentIndex) {
      if (newIndex > currentIndex) {
        for (let i = 0; i <= newIndex; i += 1) {
          const lastTab = i === newIndex;
          if (lastTab) {
            this.setShowStep(i, this.options.doneClass, this.options.activeClass);
          } else {
            this.setShowStep(i, `${this.options.activeClass} ${this.options.errorClass}`, this.options.doneClass);
          }
          const stepDirectionF = this.getStepDirection(i, newIndex);
          const validStep = this.options.onChange(i, newIndex, stepDirectionF);
          if (!validStep) {
            this.setShowStep(i, this.options.doneClass, `${this.options.activeClass} ${this.options.errorClass}`);
            this.setFooterBtns();
            break;
          }
        }
      }

      if (currentIndex > newIndex) {
        for (let i = currentIndex; i >= newIndex; i -= 1) {
          const stepDirectionB = this.getStepDirection(i, newIndex);
          this.options.onChange(i, newIndex, stepDirectionB);
          this.setShowStep(i, `${this.options.doneClass} ${this.options.activeClass} ${this.options.errorClass}`);
          if (i === newIndex) {
            this.setShowStep(i, `${this.options.doneClass} ${this.options.errorClass}`, this.options.activeClass);
          }
        }
      }

      this.setFooterBtns();
    }
  }

  setFooterBtns() {
    const stepIndex = this.getStepIndex();
    const maxIndex = this.getMaxStepCount();
    const $footer = this.el.find(this.options.footerSelector);

    if (stepIndex === 0) {
      $footer.find('button[data-direction="prev"]').hide();
    }

    if (stepIndex > 0 && this.options.showBackButton) {
      $footer.find('button[data-direction="prev"]').show();
    }

    if (maxIndex === stepIndex) {
      $footer.find('button[data-direction="prev"]').show();
      $footer.find('button[data-direction="next"]').hide();
      $footer.find('button[data-direction="finish"]').show();
    } else {
      $footer.find('button[data-direction="next"]').show();
      $footer.find('button[data-direction="finish"]').hide();
    }

    if (!this.options.showBackButton) {
      $footer.find('button[data-direction="prev"]').hide();
    }
  }

  setAction(action) {
   debugger;
    const stepIndex = this.getStepIndex();
    let nextStep = stepIndex;
    if (action === 'prev') { nextStep -= 1; }
    if (action === 'next') { nextStep += 1; }
    if (action === 'finish') {
      const validStep = this.options.onChange(stepIndex, nextStep, 'forward');
      if (validStep) {
        this.hook('onFinish');
      } else {
        this.setShowStep(stepIndex, '', 'error');
      }
    }
    if (action !== 'finish') { this.setActiveStep(stepIndex, nextStep); }
  }

  hideFooterBtns() {
    this.el.find(this.options.footerSelector).hide();
  }

  static setDefaults(options) {
    $.extend(DEFAULTS, $.isPlainObject(options) && options);
  }

}

export default Steps;
```

Y entiendo que esta función inicia todo `setAction(action)`

Como la implemento dentro de mi función definida como `function Capturar(s) {}`

Comment: Comparte más código para entenderte mejor y poder ayudarte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo ideal seria guardar la instancia e invocar al metodo necesario. Ahora suponiendo que tengas una HTML asi:

```
<div id="wizard">
    <div class="step-app">
        <ul class="step-steps">
            <li><a href="#step1">Step 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#step2">Step 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#step3">Step 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="step-content">
            <div class="step-tab-panel" id="step1">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="step-tab-panel" id="step2">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="step-tab-panel" id="step3">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="step-footer">
            <button data-direction="prev">Previous</button>
            <button data-direction="next">Next</button>
            <button data-direction="finish">Finish</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Haces referencia a los paneles asi:

```
stepsWizard = $("#wizard").steps({
    // Opciones...
});
```

Cuando quieras dar next invoca asi

```
stepsWizard.steps("next");
```

**Actualizacion**

Al parecer con el enlace mencionado no funciona el ´steps("next");´ una solucion facil simular haciendo click en boton next

Ejemplo:

```js
var miStep = $('#demo').steps({
    onFinish: function () { alert('Wizard Completed'); }
}).show();

function next(){
   $("#next").click();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oguzhanoya.github.io/jquery-steps/dist/jquery-steps.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://oguzhanoya.github.io/jquery-steps/dist/jquery-steps.css">

<div id="demo">
    <div class="step-app">
        <ul class="step-steps">
            <li><a href="#step1">Step 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#step2">Step 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#step3">Step 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="step-content">
            <div class="step-tab-panel" id="step1">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="step-tab-panel" id="step2">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="step-tab-panel" id="step3">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="step-footer">
            <button data-direction="prev">Previous</button>
            <button data-direction="next" id="next">Next</button>
            <button data-direction="finish">Finish</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button onclick="next()">Simulara que termino la lectura de huella</button>
```

Comment: Lo probare ... Gracias. Samir Llorente

Comment: Podrías por favor indicarme que significa $("#wizard").steps, navegue todo el codigo pero no encuentro una referencia a wizard.

Comment: intento importar la clase steps asi : import Steps from './Steps';  dentro de mi app.js, pero me devuelve este error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.

Comment: $("#wizard") hace referencia a tu contenedor de los paneles de navegación, he editado el código para mas entendimiento

Comment: Entiendo ahora. Sin embargo lo que busco es poder usar las funciones directamente del JS, encontré que que la función que se ejecuta en el evento next es esta : setAction(action). Por lo que intente importar la clase Steps en mi archivo app.js, ... asi :  import Steps from './Steps';, pero  obtengo este error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. Que estoy haciendo mal?